# Transaction Error: Uniswap RouterV2 Sepolia Testnet

Tags: uniswap, python, brownie, sepolia

Im trying to swap WETH -> USDC in the Sepolia Testnet using [Uniswap Router02 contract](https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0xc532a74256d3db42d0bf7a0400fefdbad7694008#writeContract).

Firstly I minted 0.5 ETH from the [Faucet](https://www.alchemy.com/faucets/ethereum-sepolia) then created a Python script that uses Brownie (had to add the Sepolia testnet by hand, here are the connection details):

```
├─id: sepolia
├─chainid: 11155111
├─explorer: https://api-sepolia.etherscan.io/api
└─host: https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/[INFURA_API_KEY]
```

Next is the Python script, note that I had to import the ERC20 ABI locally to load the USDC contract since the code in the explorer is not verified.

```
import time
import json
from brownie import *
import os

def load_config():
    config_file_path = 'config.json'  # Adjust the path as needed

    with open(config_file_path, 'r') as config_file:
        config_data = json.load(config_file)

    return config_data

def erc20_config():
    config_file_path = 'erc20_abi.json'  # Adjust the path as needed

    with open(config_file_path, 'r') as config_file:
        config_data = json.load(config_file)

    return config_data

# Load configuration
config = load_config()
erc20 = erc20_config()
os.environ["WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID"] = REDACTED
os.environ['ETHERSCAN_TOKEN'] = REDACTED
network.connect('sepolia')
user = accounts.load('test_account')

user_balance_before = weth.balanceOf(user.address) / 10**weth.decimals()
print(f"User WETH balance before: {user_balance_before} ETH")
```

> User WETH balance before: 0.019779979849524138 ETH

```
# Define contract addresses on Goerli
router_address = '0xC532a74256D3Db42D0Bf7a0400fEFDbad7694008'
weth_address = '0x7b79995e5f793A07Bc00c21412e50Ecae098E7f9'
usdc_address = '0xf08A50178dfcDe18524640EA6618a1f965821715'
router = Contract.from_explorer(router_address)
weth = Contract.from_explorer(weth_address)
#usdc = Contract.from_explorer(usdc_address)
usdc = Contract.from_abi(name="USDC Token",address=usdc_address, abi=erc20)

weth_balance_before = weth.balanceOf(user.address) / 10**weth.decimals()
usdc_balance_before = usdc.balanceOf(user.address) / 10**usdc.decimals()

print(f"User WETH balance before: {weth_balance_before} WETH")
print(f"User USDC balance before: {usdc_balance_before} USDC")
weth.approve(router.address, 499830654504108713, {'from': user})
```

> User WETH balance before: 0.019779979849524138 WETH
> User USDC balance before: 0.0 USDC
> Transaction sent: 0x59ec909dc5ade115dd345f51f51d27427739794defdce6cf560a0b5b4375ab75
> Gas price: 1.761260845 gwei   Gas limit: 29135   Nonce: 4
> WETH.approve confirmed   Block: 5335731   Gas used: 26144 (89.73%)

So the actual picture of this account is:

- 499830654504108713  ## WETH RouterV2 ALLOWANCE
- 19779979849524137 ## Test-account WETH balance
- 6593326616508046 ## Trade size

If I'm not mistaken the amountIn should be enough and the amountOut is literally whatever (0.000001 USDC) but when I try to make the transaction:

```
router.swapExactTokensForTokens(6593326616508046,1, [weth.address, usdc.address], user.address, 1000*int(time.time()+30), {'from':user.address})
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/Javier/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/brownie/network/contract.py", line 1861, in __call__
    return self.transact(*args)
  File "/Users/Javier/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/brownie/network/contract.py", line 1734, in transact
    return tx["from"].transfer(
  File "/Users/Javier/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/brownie/network/account.py", line 644, in transfer
    receipt, exc = self._make_transaction(
  File "/Users/Javier/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/brownie/network/account.py", line 727, in _make_transaction
    raise VirtualMachineError(e) from None
  File "/Users/Javier/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/brownie/exceptions.py", line 93, in __init__
    raise ValueError(str(exc)) from None
ValueError: Gas estimation failed: 'execution reverted'. This transaction will likely revert. If you wish to broadcast, you must set the gas limit manually.
```

I've tried playing around with the parameters but have not been able to make the transaction go through. Could someone help me understand what am i doing wrong?